# How to loop through .txt and use values of each line as variables Linux Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, automation

Edited to help clarify

Goal: Design a shell script that will allow me to create variables from a text file that can later be called by larger script

Input file: TEST.txt

```
sequence010 FY11
sequence010 FY12
sequence020 FY11
sequence020 FY12
...
```

Each line represents the members that will need leveraged simultaneously to represent different POVs, i.e.:

```
POV01=sequence010 FY11
POV02=sequence010 FY12
POV03=sequence020 FY11
POV04=sequence020 FY12
...
```

The plan is to structure it in a way that I can create the variable as such:

```
POV01=$sequence, $year
POV02=$sequence, $year
POV03=$sequence, $year
export POV01 POV02 POV03
```

This main issue is how can I read them sequentially, line by line, in a way that the correct sequence and year variables parse to the correct POV?

I have tried a while loop, if statements with nested while loops, xargs,awk....all to no avail. The closest I have come is a while loop that creates the sequence and year variables, but the problem is each line needs to stay related, as the combination of the variables gives the POV.

Comment: Does it have to bee a loop?

Comment: it doesn't have to be a loop, I just need each line split into two variables that can later be called.

Comment: Perhaps if you give a little more detail about what you intend on doing with these variables, we may be able to advise you on a better approach, possibly using awk.

Comment: this will be used in an automation script, where the .txt will determine the POV selections. Each line will represent a different selection, i,e, SEQ010 FY15 is a specific POV that will need populated. The idea is the POV can be exported for a particular sequence and year combo that resides in the .txt (currently have: export pov_01="\"$sequence,$year\""...this issue is these variables are explicit and we need them to be dynamic from the .txt

Comment: If it helps, business models will be executed based on POV selections in the .txt

Comment: Why do you need them as variables?  If you need dynamic random access, just keep the data in the file and access it as needed.  That is, when you need it, find it in the file.  If multiple sequential access using `grep` is too slow, sort the file and do the lookups with `look`.  There's no need to put the data in the shell's memory.

Comment: I thought I replied, but don't see it here....basically the goal here is all automation. We want to be able to select the POV's from a form using flags, which then outputs to this .txt file. We then want this .txt files POV selections to be fed into an automation script. This is already done, but the existing variables are static, while the new ones will not be. What I am needing to do is say  POV(n)=sequence(n) year(n) where each line is its own POV....then export POV, and for execution it will be if POV1 then, if POV2 then etc.

Comment: @PrestonAlexander Instead of adding more comments here, it would be best to edit your original question with a brief (but detailed) example of both the input you expect and the output you would like to generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell variables with a space should be in quotes.
Make a file with the new shell settings, and source that file in the current shell with a dot (.).

```
;> cat TEST.txt
sequence010 FY11
sequence010 FY12
sequence020 FY11
sequence020 FY12

;> cat runit
counter=1
while read -r line; do
        printf 'POV%02d="%s"\n' ${counter} "${line}"
        (( counter = counter + 1 ))
done < TEST.txt > output.txt

;> ./runit

;> cat output.txt
POV01="sequence010 FY11"
POV02="sequence010 FY12"
POV03="sequence020 FY11"
POV04="sequence020 FY12"

;> . output.txt

;> set | grep "^POV"
POV01='sequence010 FY11'
POV02='sequence010 FY12'
POV03='sequence020 FY11'
POV04='sequence020 FY12'

;> echo ${POV02}
sequence010 FY12
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this. I am able to produce the output.txt, but if I attempt to source it as seen above, I am getting "cannot open [No such file or directory]"

Comment: it looks in here like you sourced a txt file??

Comment: Does the output.txt file have the lines as suggested? Did you start the line with a dot and not with ; or > ?

Comment: The file is named `output.txt` not `output`. On Linux you must always give the full filename, the extension doesn't really matter. Calling it output.cfg or output.ini would look a bit more accurate, but I can also call the file `output.PA`. And run `. output.PA` including the .PA.

Comment: $ cat output.txt
POV00=""
POV01="SEQ010   FY15"
POV02="SEQ010   FY16"
POV03="SEQ020   FY15"
POV04="SEQ020   FY16"
POV05="SEQ030   FY15"
POV06="SEQ030   FY16"
POV07="SEQ030   FY15"
POV08="SEQ030   FY16"
POV09="SEQ040   FY15"
POV10="SEQ040   FY16"
POV11="SEQ050   FY15"
POV12="SEQ050   FY16"

Comment: ksh ? You tagged it as linux/bash. In ksh you must add the current dir (./) with `. ./output.txt` or switch to bash.

Comment: Ahh, thanks...knew I was missing something small. My next step is to take this output.txt and create a script that will allow me to do something like select $sequence $year from output.txt where $POV=POV01, or an if/then  .sh for each POV to grab the sequence/year

Comment: Glad being helpful. Can you accept the answer ?
For further processing an output file in the format POV02 SEQ010 FY16 might be better, that way you can use `cat output.PA | while read pov seq fy; do`.

Comment: I marked as correct, but still wondering about this last piece. I changed the output to be POV02 SEQ010 FY16, but then I cant make POV=$SEQ$FY via . ./output.txt (i get ksh: .[2]: FY15: not found [No such file or directory])...ultimately I am going to need seq and fy read into an executable, so want to define in a variables file as EXPORT POV(n)=$SEQ,$FY.....any ideas? I can start a new post if you would like

Comment: Make a new post when the following doesn't help. The new format is not fit for sourcing, it can be used for getting tuples in a while loop. Another idea would be using POV01_SEQ and POV01_YR. Just think how your exec would like to get the vars: environment settings, reading a file, read from stdin of a very long list of arguments.